# Angular js testing a directive with md-option

Tags: angularjs, angular-material

I am trying to write unit test for a directive which uses `md-select`. I can target the `md-select` element, but cannot get access to the `md-option` elements.

directive.js:

```
angular.module('myApp')

 .directive('myDirective', function ($rootScope) {
   return {
     restrict: 'A',
       scope: {
        foo: '=',
     },
     templateUrl: 'static/partials/my-directive.tmpl.html',
     link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
       ...
       scope.options = [
         {
           name: 'Download', fn: function() {
             console.log('download');
           },
         },
         {
           name: 'Share', fn: function() {
             console.log('share');
           },
         },
       ];
     }
  };
});
```

directive.tmpl.html:

```
<md-input-container>
  <md-select ng-model="option" placeholder="Options">
    <md-option ng-value="opt" ng-click="opt.fn()" ng-repeat="opt in options">{{ opt.name }}</md-option>
  </md-select>
</md-input-container>
```

directive.spec.js

```
describe('My Directive', function () {
  var elm, scope;

  beforeEach(module('scriptspeakerApp'));
  beforeEach(module('templates'));

  beforeEach(inject( function ($rootScope, $compile) {
    elm = angular.element(
     '<div my-directive foo="script"></div>'
    );
    $scope = $rootScope.$new();
    $scope.foo = 'bar';
    elm = $compile(elm)($scope);
    $scope.$digest();

  }));

  it('should have one select element and 2 md-option elements', function () {
    var select = elm.find('md-select');
    select.triggerHandler("click");
    var options = elm.find('md-option');
    console.log('options', options);
    // output: Object{}
  });
```

I realize that `Angular Material` loads the `md-option` elements at the bottom of the page. Does this mean that the options cannot be accessed in the scope of the directive, and instead require an e2e test?

Comment: I noticed this was posted a while ago, have you by any chance solved this?  I'm having trouble with the same thing.

Comment: I believe I solved a similar problem to this but with md-dialog. Have a look at my question / answer - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36149361/testing-component-that-opens-md-dialog/38181656#38181656

Answer (score -1):

The problem is probably the the valid format of your javascript, as there are several trailing commas which should be removed. You need to change scope.options to

```
scope.options = [
     {
       name: 'Download', fn: function() {
         console.log('download');
       } // Removed comma from here
     },
     {
       name: 'Share', fn: function() {
         console.log('share');
       } // Removed comma from here
     } // Removed comma from here
   ];
```

I've added an example of testing a directive based on yours to an example I created about testing md-dialog based components

https://github.com/gseabrook/md-dialog-test-issue